# Open loop oscillating

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability

Will an open loop op amp with negative phase margin oscillate?

I understand phase margin is defined in closed loop transfer function with equating denominator to zero . But will an insufficient phase margin show signs for open loop connected op amp?

Comment: Beware of parasitic components such as stray capacitance, that may accidentally provide feedback, unintentionally closing the loop.

Comment: How would you use an opamp without negative feedback? You get a comparator like circuit, well if you put the feedback then the phase margin comes to play.

Comment: For example a LNA which shall be belonged to the class of op amp. Ignoring unwanted parasitic feedback, I think the amp is intended to be used in open loop.

Comment: LNAs in RF front ends tend to have finite, defined and quite low gain (10dB to 20dB). They are generally not opamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an open loop system will not oscillate. Comparators are a good example for this.

The phase margin is determined for the open loop system but is relevant for the closed system only.